# What does "get milked" mean

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

There's a site http://getmilked.com/ with satirical comics. I already googled for the definition of [get milked](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=get+milked+meaning&pbx=1&oq=get+milked+meaning&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=788l788l0l1159l1l1l0l0l0l0l226l226l2-1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=6ef3c429505fe866&biw=1280&bih=933).

What I got from googling is the following definitions:

`To draw out or extract something from...`, `To obtain money or benefits from...`

so based on the satirical context, the site has, these definitions doesn't really make sense. So  what's the real meaning of `get milked`?

Comment: Niko G. - have you read the "about" section of the website? It explains what the site is about.

Comment: @Matt of course I have and yes I know what the site is about. I just don't get the context of "get milked". I'll rephrase question: when a person "gets milked" viewing some satirical content, what is the meaning of "get milked"?

Comment: @MattЭллен: Wrong link - sorry. http://www.webtalkforums.com/showthread.php/9791-Site-update-badly-needed-Get-Milked *Lastly, is the name "Get Milked" off-putting? I know in some regions it has naughty connotations, but I do not mean it that way. I mean it more in a tongue-and-cheek sense of "Get Ripped Off.*

Comment: @shinynewbike I think you should make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, the author of that blog explains it on [this PHP forum](http://www.webtalkforums.com/showthread.php/9791-Site-update-badly-needed-Get-Milked)

> Lastly, is the name "Get Milked" off-putting? I know in some regions
>   it has naughty connotations, but I do not mean it that way. I mean it
>   more in a tongue-and-cheek sense of "Get Ripped Off.

I'm not sure if this is a standard usage of "Get Milked", it seems to be the author's own invention

Comment: Thanks for you effort. I'll vote up your answer. And guess there's nothing left but to accept it. however I'll wait a bit more to see if there are any other explanations for "get milked".

Answer (score 1):

you "milk someone" when you make them give up something of their own ( cash/ kind) for your benefit. This is used in a negative sense... where the one who "gets milked" doesn't get anything in return

I feel a good way to understand would be to imagine a cow getting milked. The milk is meant for it's calf, but we take more than a fair share of it

Eg: Banks milk customers by hiking interest rates

Answer (score 0):

To "milk something" (sometimes seen as "milk it for all it's worth") is to keep pushing well beyond what you would normally have expected.  For example, perhaps your cable company is a local monopoly and nails you with fee after fee after fee, so the apparently-low rate isn't so low after all; they can be said to be "milking" their customers.  It works for non-tangibles too; say you've had a minor disagreement with somebody, but in telling the story to your friends you exaggerate the emotional harm to you; you're "milking" the situation.

"Got milk?" is an advertising slogan from, yes, the milk industry.  "Get milked" is a play on that.

Comment: I don't see how you've jumped from "I mean it more in a tongue-and-cheek sense of "Get Ripped Off" (quoting the website owner) to stating "Get Milked" is a play on "Got Milk?", since that is not stated by the site owner anywhere. I think the phrase, as it is used by the site, is unrelated to that slogan.

Comment: I think (based only on what I've learned of this site in this discussion) that they are independent factors -- "milked" in the sense of "ripped off" is the motivation, and "get milked" is a catchy name because of the popular ad campaign.